# java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton canno be cast to android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I want to make badge drawable. when I tried to build 
Error results : java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable
I dont know how to solve it. Anyone can help?

Activity

```
class DetailItemViewActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

private val _tag = DetailItemViewActivity::class.java.simpleName
    var notificationCountCart = 0
    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details)

}

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true)

        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)

        var actionView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_app_bar,null)
        supportActionBar?.setCustomView(actionView)

        var actionBack = actionView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.btn_appbar_back)
        actionBack.setOnClickListener {
            val i = Intent(it.context, MainActivity::class.java)
            it.context.startActivity(i)
        }

        var actionCart = actionView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.btn_appbar_cart)
        actionCart.setOnClickListener{
            notificationCountCart++
            NotificationCountSetClass.setNotifyCount(notificationCountCart)
            invalidateOptionsMenu()
            val i = Intent(it.context, CartViewActivity::class.java)
            it.context.startActivity(i)
        }
        return true
    }

    override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        var actionView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_app_bar,null)
        var item = actionView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.btn_appbar_cart)
        NotificationCountSetClass.setAddToCart(this@DetailItemViewActivity, item, notificationCountCart!!)
        invalidateOptionsMenu()
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
```

NotificationCountSetClass

```
class NotificationCountSetClass : Activity() {
    companion object {
        private var icon: LayerDrawable? = null

        fun setAddToCart(context: Context, item:ImageButton, numMessage: Int) {
            icon= item.btn_appbar_cart as LayerDrawable
            SetNotificationCount.setBadgeCount(context, icon!!, NotificationCountSetClass.setNotifyCount(numMessage))


        }

        fun setNotifyCount(numMessage: Int): Int {
            return numMessage
        }
    }
}
```

object SetNotificationCount

```
object SetNotificationCount {
    fun setBadgeCount(context: Context, icon:LayerDrawable, count:Int) {

        val badge: BadgeDrawable

        val reuse = icon.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.notice_badge)

        if (reuse !=null && reuse is BadgeDrawable) {

            badge = reuse

        } else {

            badge = BadgeDrawable(context)

        }

        badge.setCount(count)
        icon.mutate()
        icon.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.notice_badge, badge)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error happens here

```
icon= item.btn_appbar_cart as LayerDrawable
```

Just because item.btn_appbar_cart is View

Try item.btn_appbar_cart.backgroud if you want get background LayerDrawable